# Storing small numbers in matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

My matrix only stores the first 4 d.p of my values. If all values within the matrix are small, then we might get to see more d.p. because it will say that all elements are for example multiplied by 1.0e-03. But this isn't really good enough, as sometimes my matrix should be comprised of very small as well as larger numbers.

Basically I am often getting an output of 0.0000 instead of what i suspect may be something more like 0.00000001. Is there a way to change this, for example matrix tolerances?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: try format long and then view your matrix, is the problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing

```
format longg
```

and reinspect your matrix. This changes the [display output format](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/format.html).

Comment: @Dennis Jaheruddin: that's not a typo, `longg` is a format, with `long`, there is still that anoying `1.0e-xx` multiplier in front of the matrix if it spans a few numeric orders.

Comment: Actually, "longg" and "long g" are the same.

Comment: yeah of course, I'm just too lazy to type that extra space :p